# android studio 3.0 stuck at "building gradle project info"

Tags: android, gradle, android-studio-3.0

Today I was going to make a new project in Android Studio. The Android Studio on my computer is updated to 3.0. When I was creating a new project and finished the procedure of the settings, the AS stuck at "Building Gradle Project info".

I have met this situation several times in AS 2.3.3, and I solved them by modifying the gradle distributionUrl. But this time, it doesn't work.

I hope someone can give me a hand. Thanks anyway!

Comment: it will not stuck it will take some time , you should wait for 5-10 min @Zeng Tianyu

Comment: and tell if you have solved the problem

Comment: But I have waited for an hour, and it seems still building gradle project info...  @Dheeraj Joshi

Comment: are you connected to the internet?

Comment: Yes, I have connected to the Internet. @Dheeraj Joshi

Comment: try the answer below , i hope it will help

Comment: and make me informed if it get solved or not

Comment: Did you solve the problem? @ZengTianyu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because downloading Gradle takes a lot of time when your network situation is not so good, you have to download it by yourself.
**My solution is:**
1. **Download a new version of gradle**, such as gradle-4.3-all.zip, etc., and put the file in your AS Gradle location (**Mac**: go to the Application folder and open the package of AS, and put the new gradle in the Gradle folder. PS: If your new gradle version folder is not found, then you can create it on your own.**Windows**: like the previous two answers);
2. **Disconnect your Wifi or LAN;**
3. Open Android Studio 3.0 as usual;
4. **DO NOT OPEN YOUR PROJECT IMMEDIATELY, TURN TO THE PREFERENCE PART FIRST;**
5. **GO TO THE GRADLE PART, DO THE SETTINGS AND SWITCH THE OFFLINE MODE ON;**
6. Open the project you want to open;
7. Let AS to index the file and **modify the gradle.properties when it is still indexing.**
8. **Turn on you Wifi or LAN,** and AS will download the missing file.
**ATTENTION: DO NOT MODIFY YOUR ANDROID MANIFEST OR OTHER FILES WHEN DOWNLOADING**
9. **Close AS and reopen the project.** And everything will be fine. :-)

If you still stuck at "Building Gradle Project info", just redo all of these. Still not clear? Comment below.

Comment: This is the perfect answer. To switch offline mode on (Configure -> Preferences -> search for gradle -> then check the work offline radio button)
Also when everything is done uncheck the offline radio button otherwise errors may occur.

Answer (score 3):

## Problem

AS 3.0 is trying to download a new version of gradle but it is taking too much time.

## Solution

1. Make sure to close AS 3.0
2. Go to the folder: C:\Users\[username]\.gradle\wrapper\dists
3. Note the latest version of gradle present there (**gradle-4.1-all** in my case)
4. Go to http://downloads.gradle.org/distributions and download the zip archive for this exact version (**gradle-4.1-all.zip** in my case)
5. Copy the archive in this gradle sub-folder, something like : C:\Users\[username]\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.1-all\c64ydeuardnfqctvr1gm30w53 ;
   delete the file with **.part** extension in this folder, it is the one AS 3.0 was trying to download.
6. Unzip the downloaded archive in this folder.

   - Create a copy of the present **.lck** file (0 KB) with the **.ok** extension (**gradle-4.1-all.zip.ok** in my case). I noticed that there are **.ok** files in other gradle version folders but I do not know if this is necessary.
7. Run AS 3.0, it should be fine now.

Comment: The link that worked for me is https://services.gradle.org/distributions/ as mentioned by @Tamil Tutorials

Answer (score 3):

### Problem

1. Android Studio 3.0 or later is trying to download a new version of gradle automatically but it is taking too much time
2. During download time network issue can stuck at building gradle project info

[image sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oz4OL.png)

### Solution for Microsoft Windows 7,8,10

1. Make sure to close Android Studio 3.0 or later version
2. Go to gradle folder: 
    C:\Users[username]\.gradle\wrapper\dists\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\ <== this long name folder can differ on your computer 
    Delete the zip archive and extracted folder name contain gradle-4.1-all.zip and gradle-4.1
3. Note the latest version of gradle present there (gradle-4.1-all in my case)
4. Go to gradle download link: https://services.gradle.org/distributions/ 
   Download the zip archive for this exact version (gradle-4.1-all.zip in my case)
5. Go to Download location of gradle-4.1-all.zip and
6. Copy gradle-4.1-all.zip archive to following location 
     C:\Users[username]\.gradle\wrapper\dists\bzyivzo6n839fup2jbap0tjew\ <== this long name folder can differ on your computer and paste it 
    it is the one Android Studio 3.0 was trying to download.
7. Extract gradle-4.1-all.zip after extraction complete you can find folder name called gradle-4.1
8. Run Android Studio 3.0, it should be fine now.

Answer (score 2):

Solution :

1). Delete the C:\Users\username.gradle folder

2). Download http://downloads.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.2.1-all.zip

3). Create a new project in android studio.

4). When this time it stucks at gradle building, Force close the android studio.

5) Now go to C:\Users\username.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-2.2.1-all\c64ydeuardnfqctvr1gm30w53 (the end directory name may be different)

6) Delete gradle-2.2.1-all.zip.lck and other files from this directory.

7) Paste the new downloaded gradle-2.2.1-all.zip here.

8) Run the android studio. :)

Comment: But AS 3.0 needs gradle-4.1 or higher version of Gradle.

Comment: than download 4.2 but i am using 4.0 only

Answer (score -1):

If you are on Windows, try to run Android Studio as an administrator