# Android Studio 3.1 stuck at "Building *** Gradle project info"

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I've recently installed AS 3.1 and whenever I create a new project AS stuck at "Building xxxx Gradle project info" for hours.
I've already followed the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47375312/6907947), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47111165/6907947), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49525681/6907947) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42979890), and none of them solved the problem.

**OS**: Windows 10

**Gradle file**: 4.4

**Gradle directory**:

`C:\Users\Ahmed\.gradle\wrapper\dists\gradle-4.4-all\9br9xq1tocpiv8o6njlyu5op1`

**Gradle directory components**:

```
 - gradle-4.4/
 - gradle-4.4-all.zip
 - gradle-4.4-all.zip.lck
 - gradle-4.4-all.zip.ok
```

Here's a screenshot:
[image]

**Update**:
After waiting for 4 hours, the program started with the following error message:

and here's the last part of the `idea.log` file:

```
2018-04-10 19:11:54,478 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - j.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider - 10386 ms spent to cache options in application 
2018-04-10 19:11:54,723 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - rd.FirstRunWizardFrameProvider - Overriding welcome frame to be resizable 
2018-04-10 19:12:26,145 [d thread 2]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading com.intellij.ide.ui.search.SearchableOptionPreloader@201f6ae4 
2018-04-10 19:12:35,171 [d thread 2]   INFO - .openapi.application.Preloader - Finished preloading com.intellij.codeInsight.completion.CompletionPreloader@67e41d09 
2018-04-10 19:21:08,465 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Subscribing project 'Project 'F:\Programming\Mobile\Opensource Android Apps\LeafPic-dev' LeafPic-dev' to indexing suspender events (com.android.tools.idea.project.IndexingSuspender@777708be) 
2018-04-10 19:21:08,666 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - ellij.project.impl.ProjectImpl - 147 project components initialized in 20284 ms 
2018-04-10 19:21:08,668 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - le.impl.ModuleManagerComponent - 0 module(s) loaded in 0 ms 
2018-04-10 19:21:15,186 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Started sync with Gradle for project 'LeafPic-dev'. 
2018-04-10 19:21:15,490 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Consuming IndexingSuspender activation event: SYNC_STARTED 
2018-04-10 19:21:21,837 [d thread 2]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre 
2018-04-10 19:21:22,251 [d thread 2]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from C:/Program Files/Android/Android Studio/jre 
2018-04-10 19:21:25,535 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - rojectCodeStyleSettingsManager - Initialized from default code style settings. 
2018-04-10 19:24:23,889 [d thread 2]   INFO - xecution.GradleExecutionHelper - Passing command-line args to Gradle Tooling API: -Didea.version=3.1 -Djava.awt.headless=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.advanced=true -Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true -Pandroid.injected.build.model.only.versioned=3 -Pandroid.injected.studio.version=3.1.1.0 -Pandroid.builder.sdkDownload=false --init-script C:\Users\Ahmed\AppData\Local\Temp\ijinit25.gradle --offline 
2018-04-10 23:11:08,898 [d thread 2]   INFO - .project.GradleProjectResolver - Gradle project resolve error 
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not run build action using Gradle distribution 'https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.4-all.zip'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ExceptionTransformer.transform(ExceptionTransformer.java:29)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.doResolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:283)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.access$200(GradleProjectResolver.java:79)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:939)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:923)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:210)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:140)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:79)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:45)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:87)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:149)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:557)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:619)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:713)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$5.run(CoreProgressManager.java:397)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:543)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:488)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$null$10(ApplicationImpl.java:575)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.NoUsableDaemonFoundException: Unable to find a usable idle daemon. I have connected to 100 different daemons but I could not use any of them to run the build. BuildActionParameters were DefaultBuildActionParameters{, currentDir=F:\Programming\Mobile\Opensource Android Apps\LeafPic-dev, systemProperties size=94, envVariables size=40, logLevel=LIFECYCLE, useDaemon=true, continuous=false, interactive=false, injectedPluginClasspath=[]}.
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:151)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:92)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:156)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.runClientAction(ProviderConnection.java:140)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:126)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:224)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerConnection$CancellableActionRunner.run(CancellableConsumerConnection.java:99)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.run(ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:84)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonInitialConnectException: The first result from the daemon was empty. Most likely the process died immediately after connection.
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.executeBuild(DaemonClient.java:170)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:141)
    ... 24 more
2018-04-10 23:11:11,606 [d thread 2]   WARN - nal.AbstractExternalSystemTask - The first result from the daemon was empty. Most likely the process died immediately after connection. 
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: The first result from the daemon was empty. Most likely the process died immediately after connection.
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.ProjectImportErrorHandler.getUserFriendlyError(ProjectImportErrorHandler.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.gradle.project.sync.idea.AndroidGradleProjectResolver.getUserFriendlyError(AndroidGradleProjectResolver.java:436)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.AbstractProjectResolverExtension.getUserFriendlyError(AbstractProjectResolverExtension.java:158)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:943)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver$ProjectConnectionDataNodeFunction.fun(GradleProjectResolver.java:923)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.execution.GradleExecutionHelper.execute(GradleExecutionHelper.java:210)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:140)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.service.project.GradleProjectResolver.resolveProjectInfo(GradleProjectResolver.java:79)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.lambda$resolveProjectInfo$0(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.execute(AbstractRemoteExternalSystemService.java:59)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.resolveProjectInfo(RemoteExternalSystemProjectResolverImpl.java:37)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.remote.wrapper.ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.resolveProjectInfo(ExternalSystemProjectResolverWrapper.java:45)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.doExecute(ExternalSystemResolveProjectTask.java:87)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:163)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.service.internal.AbstractExternalSystemTask.execute(AbstractExternalSystemTask.java:149)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$3.execute(ExternalSystemUtil.java:557)
    at com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.util.ExternalSystemUtil$4.run(ExternalSystemUtil.java:619)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$TaskRunnable.run(CoreProgressManager.java:713)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager$5.run(CoreProgressManager.java:397)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$runProcess$1(CoreProgressManager.java:157)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:543)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:488)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:94)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.runProcess(CoreProgressManager.java:144)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.lambda$null$10(ApplicationImpl.java:575)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$1.run(ApplicationImpl.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonInitialConnectException: The first result from the daemon was empty. Most likely the process died immediately after connection.
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.executeBuild(DaemonClient.java:170)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:141)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.client.DaemonClient.execute(DaemonClient.java:92)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DaemonBuildActionExecuter.execute(DaemonBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:60)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.execute(LoggingBridgingBuildActionExecuter.java:34)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:156)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.runClientAction(ProviderConnection.java:140)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ProviderConnection.run(ProviderConnection.java:126)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.DefaultConnection.run(DefaultConnection.java:224)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerConnection$CancellableActionRunner.run(CancellableConsumerConnection.java:99)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.AbstractConsumerConnection.run(AbstractConsumerConnection.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.run(ParameterValidatingConsumerConnection.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildActionExecuter$1.run(DefaultBuildActionExecuter.java:71)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.LazyConsumerActionExecutor.run(LazyConsumerActionExecutor.java:84)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.run(CancellableConsumerActionExecutor.java:45)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.run(ProgressLoggingConsumerActionExecutor.java:58)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.run(RethrowingErrorsConsumerActionExecutor.java:38)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:46)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
    ... 1 more

2018-04-10 23:11:14,353 [d thread 2]   WARN - ect.sync.idea.ProjectSetUpTask - The first result from the daemon was empty. Most likely the process died immediately after connection. 
2018-04-10 23:11:14,530 [d thread 2]   INFO - e.project.sync.GradleSyncState - Gradle sync failed: The first result from the daemon was empty. Most likely the process died immediately after connection.

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log) (3h 49m 59s 342ms) 
2018-04-10 23:11:24,533 [d thread 2]   INFO - j.ide.script.IdeStartupScripts - 0 startup script(s) found 
2018-04-10 23:11:40,980 [ thread 67]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - ExternalSystemStartupActivity run in 292ms under project opening modal progress 
2018-04-10 23:11:41,137 [ thread 67]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - ConfigProjectComponent run in 104ms under project opening modal progress 
2018-04-10 23:11:41,471 [ thread 67]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - OCInitialTablesBuildingActivity run in 259ms under project opening modal progress 
2018-04-10 23:11:41,915 [ thread 67]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - InitToolWindowsActivity run in 390ms under project opening modal progress 
2018-04-10 23:11:41,915 [ thread 67]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Post-startup activities under progress took 2185ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: ok 
2018-04-10 23:11:44,556 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - F:/Programming/Mobile/Opensource Android Apps/LeafPic-dev/.idea case-sensitivity: expected=false actual=false 
2018-04-10 23:11:45,139 [ thread 70]   INFO - pl.projectlevelman.NewMappings - VCS Root: [] - [<Project>] 
2018-04-10 23:11:50,476 [ thread 69]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Pushing properties took 6027ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: 1/2 sluggish, 1/2 very slow 
2018-04-10 23:11:53,440 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - tor.impl.FileEditorManagerImpl - Project opening took 13874787 ms 
2018-04-10 23:12:10,202 [ thread 69]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Indexable file iteration took 19598ms; general responsiveness: 1/18 sluggish, 7/18 very slow; EDT responsiveness: 0/16 sluggish, 10/16 very slow 
2018-04-10 23:12:10,208 [ thread 69]   INFO - indexing.UnindexedFilesUpdater - Unindexed files update started: 286 files to update 
2018-04-10 23:13:05,540 [ thread 69]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Unindexed files update took 55332ms; general responsiveness: 1/54 sluggish, 1/54 very slow; EDT responsiveness: 0/54 sluggish, 8/54 very slow 
2018-04-10 23:13:05,680 [ thread 69]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Clearing symbols finished in 0 s. 
2018-04-10 23:13:05,870 [ thread 69]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols in FAST mode, 0 source files from total 0 project files 
2018-04-10 23:13:06,317 [ thread 69]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loading Module Maps finished in 0 s. 
2018-04-10 23:13:06,337 [ thread 69]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving Module Maps finished in 0 s. 
2018-04-10 23:13:06,337 [ thread 69]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving Module Maps finished in 0 s. 
2018-04-10 23:13:06,338 [ thread 69]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Loaded 0 tables for 0 files (0 project files) 
2018-04-10 23:13:06,346 [ thread 69]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 source files 
2018-04-10 23:13:06,482 [ thread 69]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols for 0 unused headers 
2018-04-10 23:13:06,485 [ thread 69]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Building symbols finished in 0 s. 
2018-04-10 23:13:06,490 [ thread 69]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving modified symbols for 0 files (0 tables of total 0) 
2018-04-10 23:13:06,564 [ thread 69]   INFO -       #com.jetbrains.cidr.lang - Saving symbols finished in 0 s. 
2018-04-10 23:13:08,141 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - Some post-startup activities freeze UI for noticeable time. Please consider making them DumbAware to do them in background under modal progress, or just making them faster to speed up project opening. 
2018-04-10 23:13:08,142 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - tartup.impl.StartupManagerImpl - ProjectInspectionProfileStartUpActivity run in 1516ms on UI thread 
2018-04-10 23:13:12,220 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - j.ide.ui.OptionsTopHitProvider - 3038 ms spent to cache options in project 
2018-04-10 23:13:15,808 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - idea.project.IndexingSuspender - Starting batch update for project: Project 'F:\Programming\Mobile\Opensource Android Apps\LeafPic-dev' LeafPic-dev 
2018-04-10 23:13:22,604 [d thread 2]   INFO - g.FileBasedIndexProjectHandler - Reindexing refreshed files: 1 to update, calculated in 96ms 
2018-04-10 23:13:22,694 [d thread 2]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Reindexing refreshed files took 89ms; general responsiveness: ok; EDT responsiveness: 1/1 sluggish 
2018-04-10 23:13:25,617 [d thread 2]   INFO - g.FileBasedIndexProjectHandler - Reindexing refreshed files: 0 to update, calculated in 12ms 
2018-04-10 23:13:29,982 [d thread 2]   INFO - CompilerWorkspaceConfiguration - Available processors: 4 
2018-04-10 23:13:30,753 [d thread 2]   INFO - g.FileBasedIndexProjectHandler - Reindexing refreshed files: 212 to update, calculated in 321ms 
2018-04-10 23:13:39,277 [d thread 2]   INFO - .diagnostic.PerformanceWatcher - Reindexing refreshed files took 8524ms; general responsiveness: 2/8 sluggish, 1/8 very slow; EDT responsiveness: 0/8 sluggish, 3/8 very slow 
2018-04-10 23:24:17,350 [e-1024-b02]   INFO - ide.actions.ShowFilePathAction - 
Exit code 1
```

Comment: You're not giving folks a lot to go on here. Could we at least have a paste of the Android Studio build output, or a screenshot of something that might give a clue? What OS are you on? Can you try the build on the console instead, does that work?

Comment: Does it work if you create a different project?

Comment: @halfer thanks for your comment.
I've updated the question and added more info, also please note that I didn't use AS before and I can't start a new project or open an existing one because of the problem. If there's a log file or anything else I can do that might help you identify the cause of the problem, please let me know how to get it and I'll post it here.

Comment: @Ab_ I couldn't create any project! If there's a project thet I can download and try to open it with AS, please let me know.

Comment: Can you run the actual Gradle command on the console, to replicate what it is doing? Are they are logs you can look at, either from the GUI or the console process?

Comment: @halfer how to do that? as I said I didn't use AS before!

Comment: I've not used it either. Use a search engine? I would suggest "Android Studio Gradle logs" to start with, but persist for a full half an hour with it, without stopping. Software engineering is highly reliant on developing your search skills.

Comment: I've downloaded [this app](https://github.com/HoraApps/LeafPic) and trying to open it, but I still have the same problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured out the cause of the problem.
It was COMODO Firewall that was blocking some files.
I've marked them as trusted and the problem was solved.

If anyone faced my problem, please consider your AV or Firewall software as it might be the cause of the problem by blocking some files.

thanks for everyone tried to help!